# Delete row in Infragistics grid in Safari

Tags: safari, infragistics

How do you delete a row in an Infragistics grid in Safari? In IE and Firefox, you highlight the row, then hit the delete key (at least, that's how we implemented it). However, this does not work in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Is Safari running on a Mac? If so the key labeled “delete” is equivalent to the backspace key on a PC.